# what is a {globally|locally} static {primary|expression|range|subexpression} and what does it mean?

Tags: vhdl

Found lots of questions on SO that refer to error messages or warnings about something that is not *locally* or *globally static*.

There are many questions that ask about getting rid of such error messages, but astonishly, nobody seems to have ever asked what *static* really means.

The IEEE standard talks about *static expressions* in §9.4, but the definition isn't easy to understand (as it is recursive and - funnily enough - thus appears to be *static* itself by definition).

Thought it would be valuable to have an SO question that answers all the implications of what *static* really means in VHDL in one single place.

Comment: See 9.4.1. The reason why we pay attention to locally static  (known at analysis or 'compile' time) or globally static (known at link and load time) has to do with code generation and supplying values. There are restrictions based on semantics for strong typing, mathematic meaning and supporting VHDL as a formal notation (the synthesis eligible subset) capable of being used for formal proofs. The standard also serves for those implementing VHDL tools, the semantics need to be precise.

Comment: There's a hierarchy of definitions, the VHDL standard (the glossary, the semantics, the BNF), the (on-line) IEEE dictionary of technical terms (originally IEEE Std 100) and the Cambridge English dictionary as well as incorporated by reference standards. The semantic descriptions are precise and the standard could benefit from hypertext links encouraging the reader to understand the meaning of every word in context, the effort required is on par with scholarship.

Comment: @user1155120 yes, I know what the standard says. The question is less meant about 'what is it' than about 'what does it imply'. When I originally learnt VHDL years ago, for me this was basically just an abstract thing generating annoying error messages until I later learned it is a fundamental language feature other languages either do not have at all or (e.g. C++ TMP and `constexpr`) generated a huge hype when they 'invented' it

Comment: Semantic restrictions are based on insuring interoperability in a formal notation and represent a meeting of the mind for interested parties (tool vendors, scholars and end users) at the time a standard is adopted. Simply put its what the interested parties could agree on within the goals of The VHDL language. Here that agreement extends to when the meaning of expressions is known implying the effort needed to generate simulation model code and whether or not indirection can be required, understanding the goal is to describe the behavior of hardware formally and not abstractly.

Answer (score 0):

as stated in the comments above, a *static expression* is basically something that can be fully evaluated at compile time (either during the compilation of the design unit it is defined in - than it is said to be *locally static* - or during the evaluation of the complete design which makes it *globally static*).

This basically makes a *static expression* a constant after evaluation ('compilation'). Very similar to *constexpr* in C++.

What are the implications of this for synthesis?

One interesting usage is - considering an innocent looking footnote  in Chapter 9.4 of the standard:

*The rules for globally static expressions imply that a declared constant or a generic may be initialized with an
expression that is not globally static, for example, with a call to an impure function. The resulting constant value may be
globally static, even though its initial value expression is not. Only interface constant, variable, and signal declarations
require that their initial value expressions be static expressions.*

that you can actually use VHDL statements that are not synthesisable (like, e.g., pointers or real numbers) as long as they fulfill the *static* requirements, i.e. can be fully evaluated into synthesisable constructs at compile time:

```
architecture rtl of sintab is
    type sinus_table_type is array(natural range <>) of signed(31 downto 0);
    function sinus_table(start_value, end_value, step : real) return  sinus_table_type is
        constant table_size     : natural := 
                                  integer(ieee.math_real.ceil(
                                          end_value - start_value) / step);
        variable sintab : sinus_table_type(0 to table_size - 1);
    begin
        for i in sintab'low to sintab'high loop
            sintab(i) := to_signed(integer(
                              ieee.math_real.sin(start_value + real(i) * step) *
                              32767.0), sintab(i)'length);
        end loop;
        return sintab;
    end function sinus_table;

    function isin(sintab : sinus_table_type; us : signed) return signed is
        variable ret : signed(us'range);
    begin
        ret := sintab(to_integer(us mod sintab'length));
        return ret;
    end function isin;

    constant PI             : real := 3.1415926;
    constant stab           : sinus_table_type := sinus_table(0.0, 2.0 * PI, 0.01);
begin
    calc : process
    begin
        wait until rising_edge(clk);
        res <= isin(stab, arg);
    end process calc;
end architecture rtl;
```

In the above example, non-synthesisable expressions (using `ieee.math_real`, generally not synthesisable), are used to construct a constant array of scaled `signed` values as a lookup table, fulfilling the requirement of *static* as these expressions can be fully evaluated at compile time.